# SQL PHP UPDATE query using an array

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, arrays

I am trying to update an MS Access table using an array here is my code

```
for($i = 1; $i<=$rows; $i++)
{
    $seedsize[$i]      = $_POST['packageType'.$i];
    $RefNo[$i]         = $_POST['field'.$i];
    (int)$qtyOrder[$i] = $_POST['ordered'.$i];
    (int)$qtyDel[$i]   = $_POST['delivered'.$i];
    $unitPrice[$i]     = $_POST['unitPriceDtl'.$i];
    $ref2[$i]          = $_POST['grade'.$i];
    //$date[$i]        = $_POST['myDate'.$i];
}

$InvoiceID = $_SESSION['InvoiceID'];

$sql = "UPDATE 
            [Tbl_Invoice_Details]
        SET 
            [Seed Size]=?, 
            [RefNo]=?, 
            [Quantity Ordered]=?,
            [Quantity Delivered]=?, [Ref2]=?,
            [PricePerUnit]=?
        WHERE 
            [Invoice_ID]=?";

    $data = $conn2->prepare($sql);
    for($x = 1; $x <= 4; $x++)
    {
        $data->execute(array($seedsize[$x], $RefNo[$x], $qtyOrder[$x], $qtyDel[$x], $unitPrice[$x], $ref2[$x], $InvoiceID));
        echo $RefNo[$x]."<br/>"; 
    }
```

I am getting this error "Invalid character value for cast specification: -3030 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed that there isn't any null values in the data? Null values might be causing the cast error.

I would suggest to cast all numeric values:

```
for($i = 1; $i<=$rows; $i++)
{
    $seedsize[$i] = $_POST['packageType' . $i]; // Not sure about this one
    $RefNo[$i] = (int)$_POST['field' . $i]; 
    $qtyOrder[$i] = (int)$_POST['ordered' . $i];
    $qtyDel[$i] = (int)$_POST['delivered' . $i];
    $unitPrice[$i] = (float)$_POST['unitPriceDtl' . $i];
    $ref2[$i] = $_POST['grade' . $i]; // Not sure about this one
    //$date[$i] = $_POST['myDate' .$i];
}
```

Please note that the cast should be on the right side of the assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

Why is 4 hard coded in the 2nd for loop? Just curious.

What I think is the issue is(int)$qtyOrder[$i] or (int)$qtyDel[$i] or really anything else. The error is saying the data it expected to get is not what it got, so somewhere you sent ABC when it wanted only 123 (Numbers) for example. You should do any processing on the POST'ed information, maybe somting like:

```
$qtyOrder[$i] = intval($_POST['ordered'.$i]);
$qtyDel[$i] = intval($_POST['delivered'.$i]);
```

I've never done what your doing percisly but I think this will send you on the right track. [Here is the PHP manual page I looked at](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php).